# Chrome Extension not finding jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

We have had a chrome extension working for a while but for some reason it has suddenly stopped working - gives the error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

We have checked the manifest file against other extensions we have written and they look the same.

Our manifest looks like this

```
{
  "name": "Plane Deliveries",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.planespotters.net/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "airplane16.png",
    "default_title": "Save Selected Delivery Details"
  },    
  "icons": { "16": "airplane16.png",
           "48": "airplane48.png",
          "128": "airplane128.png" },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

When we inspect the generated background page we get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="background.js"></script>
```

The **background.js** file is

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
  //chrome.tabs.executeScript({

          chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "GetDeliveryDetails.js"});

   // code: 'alert( document.getElementById("aircraftVal").innerText);alert(document.getElementById("registrationVal").innerText);'
  //});
});
```

Which seems to indicate that jquery has been loaded first on the page.

**GetDeliveryDetails.js**

```
alert ("OK"); 
$(document).ready( function() {
    return false;   
});
```

When we run this we get the alert but then get the error $ is not defined

Any ideas why it should have stopped working

Thanks
Rich

Comment: Have you checked jquery file path is correct or its load properly. because alert is working without jquery file because it's a core javascript method. you can add this url in place of your jquery file and check. <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

Comment: Thanks Navjot,
It looks like jQuery has loaded first but I still get the error.
What is the best way to test chrome extensions as we are new to developing them.
This has been working for months and has suddenly stopped working
We also have a few other extesnions very similar and they seem to be fine.
Thanks